# Splitting an array of integers to display on one line

Tags: c#, arrays, integer

So, I've been learning JavaScript recently and now have been over the past two weeks having to learn C# too. I have converted a block of code from JS to C#. The answer is in a form of an array containing integers.

`Console.WriteLine(results[i]);` returns

```
12
457
7
99
```

However, I would like to show this on one line, but `Console.Write(results[i]);` combines the integers and returns

```
12457799
```

and I would it to show:

```
12 457 7 99
```

I've tried some rudimentary ways to fix it but have been unsuccessful.

Any tips would be appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: Without the loop, you can work with `String.Join(" ", results);`

Comment: `Console.Write(string.Join(" ", results));` prints out entire `result` array while separating items with spaces

Comment: OP's solution actually is pretty close. You can do a `Console.Write(results[i] + " ");` since the functions accepts a `string`, so as long it's a string you can format it as you want. But `String.Join` indeed is a better solution since it doesn't add space after the last element, which usually we don't want to do when we try to print multiple elements. For example, a `Console.Write(results[i] + ",");` solution will result in `12,457,7,99,` being printed.